# DataSnap XE2 and TStream method parameters

Tags: delphi, stream, datasnap

I am working on DataSnap project in Delphi XE2 using TCP/IP protocol that needs to pass a stream of binary data to the server as a method parameter. The problem I am running into is that there seems to be a size limit of about 32 KB on the stream contents. Beyond this limit the stream received at the server is empty. If I pass additional method parameters they arrive intact so it seems to be an issue at the parameter level.

Here is how the DataSnap service class is declared:

```
  TDataSnapTestClient = class(TDSAdminClient)
  private
    FSendDataCommand: TDBXCommand;
  public
    constructor Create(ADBXConnection: TDBXConnection); overload;
    constructor Create(ADBXConnection: TDBXConnection; AInstanceOwner: Boolean); overload;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure SendData(Data: TStream);
  end;
```

The approach I am using should work, at least according to the article by Jim Tierney. That said, there apparently have been changes since Delphi 2009 that have broken Jim Tierney's sample code.

[DataSnap Server Method Stream Parameters](http://blogs.embarcadero.com/jimtierney/2009/04/06/31461/)

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I traced through the client code in the debugger and found the issue is in TDBXRowBuffer.WriteBytes. Looks like this is a known problem: http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=90995

Comment: Do you see the problem only when you push data to the DS server, or when you pull data as well?  I commonly pull several megs in a single  byte stream from a DS server using `TStream`.  I used Ethereal to watch the transferred packets, and it transfers the binary data in 32k chunks until all chunks are received.

Comment: FYI - Embarcadero QC 90995 has now been closed with the resolution "As Designed". The official and correct way to handle DataSnap stream parameters is to check the stream Size property. If the value is -1 then the stream needs to be read until the Read method returns a result of zero. Thanks to James L. for pointing out the solution to this problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

DataSnap transfers the data in 32k chunks.  The receiving end has no way of knowing how many bytes will be received until after all chunks have been reassembled.  Once all the data has been received, DataSnap doesn't set the size of the `TStream` that received the data, so you can't use it until you move it to another stream that knows how many bytes are in the stream.

I know that pulling 32k+ from a DataSnap server is not the same as pushing 32k+ to a DataSnap server, but this may work for you as well.  Try running the `TStream` through this code after the DataSnap server finishes receiving the data:

```
procedure CopyStreamToMemoryStream(const ASource: TStream; var ADest: TMemoryStream; const Rewind: Boolean = True);
const
  LBufSize = $F000;
var
  LBuffer: PByte;
  LReadCount: Integer;
begin
  GetMem(LBuffer, LBufSize);
  ADest.Clear;
  try
    repeat
      LReadCount := ASource.Read(LBuffer^, LBufSize);
      if LReadCount > 0 then
        ADest.WriteBuffer(LBuffer^, LReadCount);
    until LReadCount < LBufSize;
  finally
    FreeMem(LBuffer, LBufSize);
  end;
  if Rewind then
    ADest.Seek(0, TSeekOrigin.soBeginning);
end;
```

I can't remember where I found this code (years ago), so I can't give credit where credit is due, but it has been working for me reliably for years now.

Comment: Thanks! That resolved the problem. On the server side I am using AnyDAC to pass the stream contents to a stored procedure. Apparently the logic used to read from the stream depends on the stream size rather than checking the byte count returned by the stream Read method.

Answer (score 0):

I got thinking about it and it occurred to me that transferring the data to another memory stream just wastes memory, especially if the file is very large.  All we need to do is count the bytes and set the stream size, right?!

```
procedure FixStream(const AStream: TStream);
const
  LBufSize = $F000;
var
  LBuffer: PByte;
  LReadCount, StreamSize: Integer;
begin
  GetMem(LBuffer, LBufSize);
  try
    StreamSize := 0;
    repeat
      LReadCount := AStream.Read(LBuffer^, LBufSize);
      Inc(StreamSize, LReadCount);
    until LReadCount < LBufSize;
    AStream.Size := StreamSize;
  finally
    FreeMem(LBuffer, LBufSize);
  end;
end;
```

Do you want to give that a try?  I'm not able to test the code right now or I would...

Comment: This should be an edit to your other answer. Also, you have a clear misconception of what const and var mean for reference types.

Comment: This approach won't work since the underlying DataSnap stream implementation in TDBXStreamReaderStream is designed to read the stream contents in chunks and cannot store the full contents of the stream. A stream wrapper class could be created to buffer the full stream, but that would not really be an improvement over the stream copy approach.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - The other answer was already accepted as the correct answer, so I though it best to leave it as-is.  Thanks for the comment about const versus var.  'const' is more appropriate in this case.

Comment: @DavidTaylor - Since this won't work, we could delete the answer, but your comment adds useful insight, so perhaps we should just leave it...

Comment: const doesn't do anything very useful either

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - I read an article once that recommends using 'const' when 'var' is not appropriate for all params (http://delphitools.info/2010/07/28/all-hail-the-const-parameters/). Upon closer examination, the article says not to use 'const' for objects (only to avoid confusion when others look at your code). How are objects passed when no reference type is used?

Comment: Delphi object instances are always passed as a pointer behind the scenes. Adding const to an object parameter simply prevents the pointer from being reassigned within the routine being called (e.g. set to nil or pointed to a different instance). The object instance itself can always be accessed and modified regardless of whether const is specified.