# Delphi (DataSnap) Slow

Tags: delphi, datasnap

I have recently started using DataSnap in Delphi to produce what will be a RESTful web service. After following guides by the man himself Marco Cantu and several others on the internet I have successfully got the whole 'chain' working.

But there is a small issue of speed; the client can now send a stream (along with it's size) to the server (which, because of the bug here [DataSnap XE2 and TStream method parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12097470/datasnap-xe2-and-tstream-method-parameters/12099038#12099038), is read upto the sent size), and the server will reassemble it into a file and save it on disk.

But foir a 3.66MiB file, this takes over 50 seconds!

Should this be the case? On the server I have:

```
try
   F := TFileStream.Create('written.dat', fmCreate);
   F.Position := 0;
   F.CopyFrom(Data, DataSize);
finally 
   F.Free;
```

And on the client end:

```
var
  Server: TServerMethods1Client;
  DBStream: TFileStream;
begin
  Server := TServerMethods1Client.Create(SQLConnection1.DBXConnection);
  try
    DBStream := TFileStream.Create('DataSnapServer.exe', fmOpenRead);
    DBStream.Position := 0;
    Showmessage(IntToStr(Server.SendData(DBStream, DBStream.Size)));
  finally
    Server.Free;
```

Any help appreciated!

Cheers,
Adrian

Comment: "*Should this be the case?*" No, but it may be a network issue. What happens if you just copy a file that size to the server? What do you see if you ping/tracert the server?

Comment: Sorry, both are on the same computer; that is, connecting to localhost

Comment: Sounds like an implementation bug: waiting for the timeout to be reached then truncate the returned content. It should handle the Content-Length HTTP header.

Comment: Not the answer, but to say it is feasible: our *mORMot* RESTFul framework handles [custom stream content as expected](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2012/03/28/Return-custom-content-from-an-interface-based-service), just via `interface`-defined services (no need to go through all the DataSnap plumbings and wizards, and with very good speed) - it can even uses the [http.sys kernel-mode server to process the file](http://synopse.info/forum/search.php?search_id=613347850) with no memory copy in the userland memory.

Comment: Since you're writing a .exe file, could it be that a virus scanner is agressively scanning the file while it is written? I think TFileStream automatically buffers reads and writes per 4Kb, which could cause quite a number of re-scans while the file is written.

Comment: Turns out that I was writing to a TMemo on the server trace; disabling this really fixes the problem, although I tried the virus scanner one prior - good recommendation! I am guessing the OnTrace is threaded and automatically executes a critical section to make it threadsafe?

Answer (score 1):

On server side, try adjusting `BufferKBSize` property on `TDSHTTPWebDispatcher` component. Same property can be found on `TsqlConnection` component on client.