# Android Datasnap Send Image

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, datasnap, delphi-10.4.2

I have an Android App , where I save the image and convert it to PNG .

```
  Stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    Stream.Position:=0;
    Surf := TBitmapSurface.Create;
    try

      Surf.Assign(imgObject.Bitmap);

      // convert BMP to PNG
      TBitmapCodecManager.SaveToStream(Stream,Surf,'.png');

    finally
      Surf.Free;
    end;

    // here do the save to file which we later upload
    FileDate:=FormatDateTime('yyyymmddhhnnsszzz',now);

    IniWrite(Main.FilePath+'/temp.BatchData','DATA','LocationID',ID);
    IniWrite(Main.FilePath+'/temp.BatchData','DATA','BatchNumber',edtBatch.Text);
    IniWrite(Main.FilePath+'/temp.BatchData','DATA','Type','BatchTrack');

    // write the image
    Stream.SaveToFile(Main.FilePath+'/'+FileDate+'.img');

    RenameFile(Main.FilePath+'/temp.BatchData',Main.FilePath+'/'+FileDate+'.out');
  finally
    Stream.Free;
  end;
```

Since I had to make sure the Image is saved correctly I created a test procedure for it :

```
procedure TMain.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var tmpFiles : TStringDynArray;
    Files : TStringDynArray;

    ImageFile : string;
    Image : TMemoryStream;

    surf : TBitmapSurface;
    Bitmap : TBitmap;
begin

   Files := TDirectory.GetFiles(FilePath+'/','*.out');

  ImageFile := ChangeFileExt(Files[0],'.img');

  Image := TMemoryStream.Create;

  Image.LoadFromFile(ImageFile);

  Image.Position:=0;

  surf := TBitmapSurface.Create;

  TBitmapCodecManager.LoadFromStream(Image,surf);

  Image1.Bitmap.Assign(surf);

end;
```

The Image loads correctly on the Android device.

I have following function to upload data via DataSnap :

```
LocationID := inireadInt(Files[0],'DATA','LocationID');
BatchName := inireadStr(Files[0],'DATA','BatchNumber');

ImageFile := ChangeFileExt(Files[0],'.img');

Image := TMemoryStream.Create;
Image.LoadFromFile(ImageFile);
Image.Position:=0;

if FileType = 'BatchTrack' then
begin
  if Temp.BATCH_TRACK(LocationID,BatchName,Image) = 1 then
  begin
    System.SysUtils.DeleteFile(Files[0]);
  end;
end;
```

The BATCH_TRACK function itself on the client looks like this :

```
function TServerMethods1Client.BATCH_TRACK(HeadID: integer; BatchNumber: string;
  Image: TMemoryStream): integer;
begin

  if FBATCH_TRACKCommand = nil then
  begin
    FBATCH_TRACKCommand := FDBXConnection.CreateCommand;
    FBATCH_TRACKCommand.CommandType := TDBXCommandTypes.DSServerMethod;
    FBATCH_TRACKCommand.Text := 'TServerMethods1.BATCH_TRACK';
    FBATCH_TRACKCommand.Prepare;
  end;

  FBATCH_TRACKCommand.Parameters[0].Value.SetInt32(HeadID);
  FBATCH_TRACKCommand.Parameters[1].Value.SetWideString(BatchNumber);
  FBATCH_TRACKCommand.Parameters[2].Value.SetStream(Image,FInstanceOwner);

  FBATCH_TRACKCommand.ExecuteUpdate;

  Result := FBATCH_TRACKCommand.Parameters[3].Value.GetInt32;
end;
```

on the Server itself I now have a empty function :

```
function TServerMethods1.BATCH_TRACK(HeadID : integer; Batchnumber : string; Image : TMemoryStream) : integer;
var MS : TMemoryStream;
begin

  try
 
    MS := TMemoryStream.Create;
    MS.LoadFromStream(Image);
    MS.Position:=0;
    
    Result := 1;
  except
    Result := -1;
  end;
    
end;
```

I get a Invalid Typecast error when debugging the client .

Please help.

**UPDATE 1**

I have changed both Server and Client from TMemoryStream to TStream.
This works but only for very small files.

If I try to send an image for example 75Kbyte . I get a Unable to Expand Memory Stream due to lack of memory .

Comment: I think that server method's parameter `Image` should be of `TStream` type instead of `TMemoryStream`.

Comment: @PeterWolf : you are right, I was looking at examples from Embarcadero . I have changed it to TStream. And it does work but only with very small files. If I try to upload a file which is 75 Kbyte in size I get a : Unable to Expand Memory Stream due to lack of memory

Comment: Now that's another question and you didn't include its details: where does the error occur? what is the exact error message? what is the code to reproduce issue. See also: [DataSnap XE2 and TStream method parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12097470).

Comment: @PeterWolf : just updated the Question ... corrected the Server Method with actual code which is causing the trouble.

Comment: @PeterWolf you are the man! . That CopyStreamToMemoryStream solved my problem. If you wish you can answer this question with that and we can close this.

Comment: @PeterWolf : I've read the answer till the end on the other Post "
DataSnap transfers the data in 32k chunks. The receiving end has no way of knowing how many bytes will be received until after all chunks have been reassembled. Once all the data has been received, DataSnap doesn't set the size of the TStream that received the data, so you can't use it until you move it to another stream that knows how many bytes are in the stream." That explains it.

Comment: Then it's duplicate of [DataSnap XE2 and TStream method parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12097470/datasnap-xe2-and-tstream-method-parameters)